# Print string list vertically

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataframe as below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['x','y','z','aa'], 'Result': [2, 5, 11, 16]})
```

I want to return a text string only including those which are more than 10.

example of the result i want is below

```
From the results in df, the below returned greater than 10:
    z
    aa
```

I have tried the below, but it didn't give the output that i was looking for. It gave an array in the same line. Not as the above.

```
df2 = df[df['Result']>= 10]
df3 = df2['Title'].values

print ('From the results in df, the below returned greater than 10:\n\t%s' (df3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight alteration from @membraneporential.

```
print ('From the results in df, the below returned greater than 10:\n\t', '\n\t'.join(df3))
```

Comment: ah yes much more concise, don't know why I thought the generator expression was necessary

Answer (score 2):

change

```
print ('From the results in df, the below returned greater than 10:\n\t%s' (df3))
```

to

```
print ('From the results in df, the below returned greater than 10:')
for n in df3:
    print('\t' + str(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea, just join the values together with regular python:

```
long_values = df.loc[df['Result'] >= 10, 'Title']
print('From the results in df, the below returned greater than 10:')
print('\n'.join('\t' + s for s in long_values))
```

Out:

```
From the results in df, the below returned greater than 10:
    z
    aa
```